# Save BitmapImage to File

Tags: c#, save, bitmapimage

I am working on a program that downloads images from a URL to a bitmapimageand displays it. Next I try to save the bitmapimage to the harddrive using jpegbitmapencoder. The file is successfully created but the actual jpeg image is empty or 1 black pixel.

```
public Guid SavePhoto(string istrImagePath)
{
    ImagePath = istrImagePath;

    BitmapImage objImage = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(istrImagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    PictureDisplayed.Source = objImage;
    savedCreationObject = objImage;

    Guid photoID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    string photolocation = photoID.ToString() + ".jpg";  //file name

    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(objImage));

    using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(photolocation, FileMode.Create))
    {
        encoder.Save(filestream);
    }

    return photoID;
}
```

This is the function that saves and displays the photo. The photo is displayed correctly but again when it is saved I get an empty jpeg or 1 black pixel.

Comment: Just use encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(new WriteableBitmap(objImage)));

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you create your BitmapImage from a Uri, time is required to download the image.

If you check the following property, the value will likely be TRUE

```
objImage.IsDownloading
```

As such, you much attach a listener to the DownloadCompleted event handler and move all processing to that EventHandler.

```
objImage.DownloadCompleted += objImage_DownloadCompleted;
```

Where that handler will look something like:

```
private void objImage_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
  Guid photoID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
  String photolocation = photoID.ToString() + ".jpg";  //file name 

  encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage)sender));

  using (var filestream = new FileStream(photolocation, FileMode.Create))
    encoder.Save(filestream);
}
```

You will likely also want to add another EventHandler for DownloadFailed in order to gracefully handle any error cases.

**Edit**

Added full sample class based on Ben's comment:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    SavePhoto("http://www.google.ca/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
  }

  public void SavePhoto(string istrImagePath)
  {
    BitmapImage objImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(istrImagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    objImage.DownloadCompleted += objImage_DownloadCompleted;
  }

  private void objImage_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    Guid photoID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    String photolocation = photoID.ToString() + ".jpg";  //file name 

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage)sender));

    using (var filestream = new FileStream(photolocation, FileMode.Create))
      encoder.Save(filestream);
  } 
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and the same problem still occurs. the jpeg saved is empty or has 1 black pixel.

Comment: @Ben - Code runs... updated answer will full sample code I used to test my answer; does that work for you? Should download the 9KB Google logo and save it to disk.

Comment: Thanks your code works perfectly and It works in my code as well. The problem as you pointed out was the photo hadn't download completely from the Uri. Again, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Chris Baxter's solution, this Converter uses the local version if it exists, otherwise downloads it and saves the file.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public sealed class UriToCachedImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var url = value as string;
            if (url == null)
                return null;

            var webUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(webUri.AbsolutePath);

            var localFilePath = Path.Combine("C:\\MyImagesFolder\\", filename);

            if (File.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(localFilePath, UriKind.Absolute));
            }

            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = webUri;
            image.EndInit();

            SaveImage(image, localFilePath);

            return image;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SaveImage(BitmapImage image, string localFilePath)
        {
            image.DownloadCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage) sender));
                using (var filestream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(filestream);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure you can access the converter within your xaml

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:u="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"          
             d:DesignHeight="500" 
             d:DesignWidth="420">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <u:UriToCachedImageConverter x:Key="UrlToCachedImageConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>            
</UserControl>
```

And use the converter on an image

```
<Image Source="{Binding URL, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource UrlToCachedImageConverter}, IsAsync=true}"/>
```