# How To save image in WPF Application in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, save

Hi i am new in  c# WPF i am creating a Diagram Maker application. it only save as .xml file to be able to edit again, but i want to save it also as image, i searched but they are using OpenFileDialog and the c# WPF doesn't support the OpenFileDialog command. I have a code like this in save.

```
<Button Margin="1" Padding="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonBaseStyle}"
                        Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Save}"
                        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="Images/image.png" Width="16"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="3,0,3,0" Text="Save" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
```

What will i do? Any ideas will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

WPF has OpenFileDialog...
In usings:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Sample:

```
OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
if (opf.ShowDialog().HasValue)
{
    string myFile = opf.FileName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very very much @Spawn, now i can finish my thesis program. i'll just search for the jpg save code.

Comment: Good sample of image save can be found here, for example - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4161485/1979354