# How to save BitmapImage in a string?

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

Is there a way to save a BitmapImage in a string or int?

So that I can save this in a .txt for example like a hex or binary.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161359/save-bitmapimage-to-file) an answer to your question?

Comment: You can save image to a stream, an array of bytes, and then what you do with the stream is up to you - saving to disk or converting to byte 64 string with `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)`

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134062/encode-a-filestream-to-base64-with-c-sharp

Comment: Tnx Martin, For helping in the right direction.This is indeed what I was looking for ```Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)```